# Get gpg key info

Tags: gpg

I have a GPG public key, and I'd like to know its name.
The key can be a file containing a text, or just the text.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this goal:

1. `gpg <key-file>`
2. `gpg`, then the user is prompted to insert text. Now copy and paste the key text

The key name and info will be printed to screen